# Probability mass function from a GAME.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

---A game is played by randomly selecting two balls from a container with 8 white, 4 black and 2 orange balls. Suppose that you win $2\text{ for each black ball selected and lose}\;\; $1 for each white ball selected. Let X denote your winnings.

***(1) Write down the probability mass function for X.***

I used O: orange; b: Black ; w: white.

Orange both times :  (O,O) = $0 {(2/14)*(1/13)}\text{
and I counted the other cases also:}
                     (O,B)= $2 {(2/14)*(4/13)}
                     (O,W)= -$1 {(8/14)*(2/13)}
                     (W,B)= $1 {(8/14)*(2/13)}
                     (W,W)=-$2 {(8/14)*(7/13)}
                     (B,B)=$4 {(4/14)(3/13)}

**My question is: how to write down this probability mass function?**

***(2) What are your expected winnings?***

**My question is: This answer is correct?**

From the data above the expected winnings is x f(x)= $0*{(2/14)*(1/13)}+$2 {(2/14)*(4/13)}-$1 {(8/14)*(2/13)}+$1 {(8/14)*(2/13)}-$2 {(8/14)*(7/13)}+$4 {(4/14)(3/13)}= N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the possible totals and events:

$$\begin{array}{rll}
x=-2: &(W,W) &\quad p=\frac{8}{14}\cdot\frac{7}{13}\\
x=-1: &(W,O)\text{ or }(O,W)&\quad p=2\cdot\frac{8}{14}\cdot\frac{2}{13} \\
x=0: &(O,O) &\quad p=\frac{2}{14}\cdot\frac{1}{13} \\
x=1: &(B,W)\text{ or }(W,B) &\quad p=2\cdot\frac{4}{14}\cdot\frac{8}{13}\\
x=2: &(B,O)\text{ or }(O,B) &\quad p=2\cdot\frac{4}{14}\cdot\frac{2}{13}\\
x=4: &(B,B) &\quad p=\frac{4}{14}\cdot\frac{3}{13} \\
\end{array}$$

The probability mass function is typically written using cases, although sometimes a formula is possible too:

$$f_{X}(x)=\begin{cases}   
\frac{56}{182},&\text{if }x=-2 \\[1em]
\frac{32}{182},&\text{if }x=-1 \\[1em]   
\frac{2}{182},&\text{if }x=0 \\[1em]     
\frac{64}{182},&\text{if }x=1 \\[1em]     
\frac{16}{182},&\text{if }x=2 \\[1em]     
\frac{12}{182},&\text{if }x=4 \\[1em]     
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The calculation as you have it for the expected value is basically correct, but 
you have not accounted for events such as $(B,O)$ and $(W,O)$. A handy check is that the sum of probabilities for different winnings must equal $1$, i.e.

$$\sum{f_X(x)}=1$$

In terms of a more formal notation, you can use $\mathbb{E}$ for the expected value:

$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum{x\cdot f_X(x)}=(-2)\frac{56}{182}+(-1)\frac{32}{182}+0+(1)\frac{64}{182}+(2)\frac{16}{182}+(4)\frac{12}{182}$$